# jQuery menu hover

Tags: jquery, css, hover

This question may have been asked before and I'm sorry if I missed it,

I have this drop down menu structure :

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a>text1</a></li>
    <li class="withchild"><a class="itemchild">text2</a>
        <ul>
        ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>text3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm changing `itemchild`'s background on `hover`.

```
$("li.withchild ul").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.itemchild').css('background','the new background');
},
function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.itemchild').css('background','the old background');
});
```

And a the CSS for `li.withchild a.itemchild:hover{the new background}`

**My problem :** If I hover over `.itemchild` the background changes, and then hover over

`li.withchild ul` , `.itemchild`'s background remains with new background. But if I hover off

`li.withchild ul` back onto `.itemchild` the background returns to old background.

**What is the best way to work around this?**

Comment: Do you need to use javascript for this?

Comment: Well yes because I don't see how I could do it with CSS : `li.withchild ul:hover{/* change .itemchild background */}` ?

Comment: Well, that's exactly the behavior that you've coded it for. Seems right to me. What was the behavior you wanted it to do?

Comment: As long as I'm on `li.withchild ul` or `.itemchild`. I want `.itemchild`'s background to be the new one (It's a downward pointing arrow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have `.itemchild` display the new background when your mouse is over EITHER `.itemchild` OR `li.withchild ul`, the best way would probably be to attach the hover to the parent element:

```
$("li.withchild").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.itemchild').css('background','the new background');
},
function(){
    $(this).find('.itemchild').css('background','the old background');
});
```

Or, you could first wrap `li.withchild ul` and `.itemchild` into a new div of their own with [wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) and then attach the event to that.

Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: Yes you are. But I could do that with CSS, my problem would be in your case when I hover over li.withchild ul the background would go back to the original one. I'll setup a jsfiddle.

Comment: If you attach the event to the parent `li.withchild` (not `li.withchild ul`) then I think it should work as desired.